# Array of objects to comma separated array javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert array of objects to comma separated string array.

Input:

```
report: [{"name":"abc","age":23,"gender":"male"},
         {"name":"def","age":24,"gender":"female"},
         {"name":"ghi","age":25,"gender":"other"}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[["abc",23,"male"],["def",24,"female"],["ghi",25,"other"]]
```

Code:

```
resultArray: any = [];

report.forEach(d => {
var energy = Object.values(d).join(",");
this.resultArray.push([energy]);
});
```

Result: `[["abc,23,male"],["def,24,female"],["ghi,25,other"]]`

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join(',')` will join array separated by `,` and you are assigning it in array as:

```
this.resultArray.push([energy]);
```

All you have to do is:

```
var energy = Object.values(d);  // get all the values of an object
this.resultArray.push(energy);  // Pust energy values in resultArray
```

```js
const report = [
    { name: 'abc', age: 23, gender: 'male' },
    { name: 'def', age: 24, gender: 'female' },
    { name: 'ghi', age: 25, gender: 'other' },
];

const resultArray = [];

report.forEach((d) => {
    var energy = Object.values(d);
    resultArray.push(energy);
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `.join(',')`, you're turning each object you're iterating over into a single string. If you want 3 separate elements, don't join.

```js
const report = [{"name":"abc","age":23,"gender":"male"},
         {"name":"def","age":24,"gender":"female"},
         {"name":"ghi","age":25,"gender":"other"}]

const resultArray = [];

report.forEach(d => {
  var energy = Object.values(d);
  resultArray.push(energy);
});
console.log(resultArray);
```

Or, better:

```js
const report = [{"name":"abc","age":23,"gender":"male"},
         {"name":"def","age":24,"gender":"female"},
         {"name":"ghi","age":25,"gender":"other"}]

const resultArray = report.map(Object.values);
console.log(resultArray);
```